# Difficult sql request

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got some troubles with a sql request.

Here are my tables :

text :

```
id     component_kind     text
56           4             a
19           4             a
10           4             a
1            6             b
```

act :

```
id    text_id    detail_id    detail_type
 1       56          2        ItemGather
 2       19          5        MonsterHunt
 3       10          6        ItemUse
```

ItemGather :

```
id     item_id    count
 2      1020        3
```

MonsterHunt :

```
id     npc_id   count
 5      256      10
```

ItemUse :

```
id    item_id   count
 6     3241       1
```

As you can see act.text_id is a foreign key of text.id and act.detail_id represents the id of one of the tables below act.

What I want to do is show something like this :

```
component_kind text gather_id gather_count use_id use_count hunt_id hunt_count
       4        a      1020        3        3241      1       256      10
       6        b       0          0          0       0        0        0
```

I don't know what to write in my request. Can any sql pro help me?

Comment: What is your actual problem? You will have to outer-join the three detail tables. Does that already answer your question?

Comment: It's also not clear what must be the logic of selecting gather_id, hunt_id, use_id and applying GROUP BY clause at the same time

Comment: Well, you join all the tables, then you group by text.component_kind and text.text. Just try it.

Comment: put your data in www.sqlfiddle.com, you will get better response, also please tag which sql you are using, oracle, mssql or mysql

Comment: I tried to outer join the tables but I got an sql syntax error. Then I tried an inner join, the request was processed without error but it returned no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, simply outer-join the tables.

I use GROUP_CONCAT for the case that there is more than one match. In MySQL it would be allowed to simply select `ig.item_id` instead of `group_concat(ig.item_id)` which would give you a random ID in case there is more than one. It's up to you what you want to show in this case.

I use COALESCE to show 0 instead of NULL for sums when there are no matching records.

```
select
  t.component_kind,
  t.text,
  group_concat(ig.item_id) as gather_ids,
  coalesce(sum(ig.count),0) as gather_count,
  group_concat(iu.item_id) as use_ids,
  coalesce(sum(iu.count),0) as use_count,
  group_concat(mh.npc_id) as hunt_is,
  coalesce(sum(mh.count),0) as hunt_count
from text t
left outer join act a on a.text_id = t.id
left outer join itemgather ig on ig.id = a.detail_id and a.detail_type = 'ItemGather'
left outer join monsterhunt mh on mh.id = a.detail_id and a.detail_type = 'MonsterHunt'
left outer join itemuse iu on iu.id = a.detail_id and a.detail_type = 'ItemUse'
group by t.component_kind, t.text;
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00cfb/10.